# how to highlight the row regardless of case sensitive using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnhighlight").click(function () {
                    var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").val();
                    if (htext == '') {
                        alert("Pleae enter the search item.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    $("#lstCodelist option").each(function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('searchItem');
                        if ($(this).text().search(htext) != -1) {
                            $(this).addClass('searchItem');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

Lets take I have a row something like this

```
I love  to work with Jquery.
```

If I enter my search text as jquery its not highlighting Jquery. But my query should work in both they way regardless of CAPS or SMALL letters.

how to change my code to work like that.

thanks for your all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.toUpperCase()` ............. // or lowerCase

```
  if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(htext.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should work, I believe:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnhighlight").click(function() {
        var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").val().toLowerCase();

        if (htext === '') {
            alert("Please enter the search item.");
            return false;
        }

        $("#lstCodelist option").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(htext) !== -1) {
                $this.addClass('searchItem');
            } else {
                $this.removeClass('searchItem');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Sidenote:** `indexOf` is [proven to be faster](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-search) than `search`.